# RESTful API examples

Tags: rest

I have been trying to understand what a RESTful API/Web Application is supposed to look like and I cant help but wonder if the Web is already built under a RESTful architecture. Every website is basically a collection of web pages (A specific representation of the state of the Web App) and you change states by clicking links. Therefore you have Representational State Transfer!

Am I wrong in thinking this? Also, every SO answer to the question 'What is REST?' which I have managed to find fails to provide an example and show the difference between a non-RESTful API and a RESTful API.

Can someone provide that please? It would help in clearing things up. I do not want abstract terms in the answer because it would be more helpful to fit the abstract answer into an example rather than try to figure out an example from an abstract answer. Beginner speaking :)

Comment: Not everything in the web is RESTful, think about sessions, cookies, user agent spoofing...^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deepak,

in a nutshell, REST in an architectural style which helps your application make the most of the Web. The term was coined in the thesis by Roy Fielding called  [Architectural Styles and the Design of Network-based Software Architectures](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm).

While a lot of  REST services use HTTP and JSON, they are not limited to the aforementioned protocol and format. To tell whether a service is RESTful or not, one can use the so-called [Richardson Maturity Model](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html). The services that are not at the level three of the model are sometimes called RESTlike.

First of all, REST services are stateless, that is if you receive a huge list from the server, which is paginated, such as a list of books from the Amazon, the page you are on isn't stored at the server side, it is the responsibility of the client to inform the server about the next page's number. Also URIs are used to identify resources, e.g. each book's description can be retrieved using its unique URI, and HTTP methods such as GET and POST are used to work with resources, for instance, the former can be used to retrieve the book info and the latter to add a new book.

The crux of the style is a concept called Hypermedia As The Engine Of An Application state([HATEOAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS)). A simplistic explanation of what it is could be that the representations of resources (book info can be in JSON, XML, HTML etc.) should use hyperlinks to make those representations self-describing, e.g. if the book info can be edited, the link to do so should be added.

There are various proposals how to add hypermedia to representations. One possible format is Hypertext Application Language ([HAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Application_Language)).  Others include but not limited to [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org/), [JSON-LD](http://json-ld.org/), [UBER](http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/05/uber-hypermedia).

Personally I ventured to elaborate on the topic in my blog:

- [What is REST?](http://javaeeeee.blogspot.com/2014/11/what-is-rest.html)
- [REST: Uniform interface](http://javaeeeee.blogspot.com/2014/11/rest-uniform-interface.html)
- [Introduction to Hypertext Application Language (HAL)](http://javaeeeee.blogspot.com/2015/02/introduction-to-hypertext-application.html)

Regards, Dmitry

Comment: Nice answer.  What do you think about the OP's suggestion that the regular Web (with its html pages and such) is a form of REST?  Can you eleborate on that in your answer?